# URL Routing and Relative Links Behavior

Tags: asp.net, url-routing

I'm building a website that stores a number of articles. The URL for each articles implements URL routing in the form /Articles/{categoryid}/{articleslug}.

Some articles have links to a graphics file. The link does not specify the full path so I'm storing the graphics file at /Articles/{categoryid}/{articleslug}/graphic.jpg.

This works fine on my desktop. But when I deployed the site to a shared hosting account, the behavior is different.

Now, the link only works if I store the graphics file at /Articles/{categoryid}/graphic.jpg. In other words, on my desktop, the {articleslug} is assumed to be a directory, but on the web it is assumed to be the name of the current page.

Does anyone know why the behavior changes? You can seen an example at http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/asp/creating-website-thumbnails-in-asp-net. Both the screenshot and download link near the top are broken links.

Comment: I've just noticed that if I append a '/' to the URL above, it is then assumed to be a directory name and the links work okay. But I still don't understand why I didn't need this on my desktop, or if I can control this.

Comment: Aside from the Development Server vs IIS described in my comment to joelt, I'm leaning towards just specifying a <base href="url"> tag in my page. That way, I should be able to precisely control the meaning of relative links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input. There probably wasn't enough information here for anyone to resolve this unless they've specifically seen the issue already.

At any rate, I was able to resolve it myself and I describe the resolution in a related question I posted at [Relative Links with Extension-less URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415716/relative-links-with-extension-less-urls).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more, it seems like the most likely cause would be a different version or configuration of IIS. The behavior of the web host makes all kinds of sense; the behavior of your desktop is confusing to me. Is your desktop doing a redirect from /Articles/{categoryid}/{articleslug} to /Articles/{categoryid}/{articleslug}/? Can you use Fiddler etc to see if the browser formats the GET request differently?

Comment: Someone else pointed out for me that Development Server handles all requests through ASP.NET handler but IIS doesn't. He indicated that if a URL ends with .aspx on IIS then it is fine. If it looks like a directory URL for IIS then it is not sent through ASP.NET handler by default. That seems be why I get different behavior running from Visual Studio.

Comment: To answer your questions more specifically, I'm not doing any redirect. I'm using ASP.NET 4.0 URL routing. And I think I have Fiddler installed but have no idea what I'd be looking for. I'm a developer but not an admin/IIS guy. Despite continued effort, this issue remains unsolved.

Comment: I don't think the ending a URL with .aspx matters. If that were the problem, your site wouldn't be working at all on the web server. Newer versions of IIS don't have that problem. I just ran a test on my machine, which has the version of the Routing library that was deployed with ASP.NET MVC 1, and it behaves similarly to your web server. You could try deploying your version of the routing dll in your bin directory and referencing that, rather than the GAC, and see what happens.

Comment: I get your point about the site wouldn't work at all if the request simply wasn't being mapped to ASP.NET. Somehow, the browser, IIS, whoever is making a determination about whether or not the URL represents a path or filename and I don't even know how this determination is made.