# How Does My Browser Know if a URL Represents a Filename or Directory

Tags: iis, url, browser

Does anyone know what mechanism is used in order for the browser to know if a given URL represents a filename or a directory?

What if any role does the server play in this? And would server participation rely on IIS? In some cases, I understood the server returns some indication if the URL represents a directory, and this causes the browser to append "/" to the URL.

I'm having a serious problem (described here:
[Relative Links with Extension-less URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415716/relative-links-with-extension-less-urls)), but I can't resolve it because I don't have any idea what the mechanism is that is failing me.

Comment: In fact, the client browser doesn't ever really know what any URL represents, be it a file, a directory or a dynamic script. It doesn't need to - the URL is just a string which is sent to the server, which sends some HTML (or another kind of content) in return.

Comment: Sure, I was just trying to understand the behavior. I didn't mean to suggest the browser was the piece that detected and triggered the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server sends a 302 redirect to a `/`-terminated path.

Comment: I guess that's what it does, although I'll be damned if I can find a description of this behavior and exactly which software does this. All my searches just turned up articles about 302 redirects in general. Thanks.