# Standard link on two different servers - different behaviour

Tags: asp.net, html, iis, hyperlink, relative-path

I couldn't find a better title for this thread, but I hope it makes sense.

I have two Windows servers:

1. Shared hosting, hosting my test site on a subdomain (test.domain.com). Windows Server 2008 R2
2. Cloud server with Windows Server 2008. I have IIS access

In my first case, I have just uploaded the application using FTP. In my second case, I've setup the IIS "as usual".

In my content, I have several links which are formed as :

```
<a href="Mylink/">Text</a>
```

The MyLink leads to a page using URL Routing. However, let's say that link is on some subpage, for instance domain.com/MySubpage, this happens:

Behaviour from server 2:

```
domain.com/MySubpage/MyLink/
```

Behaviour from server 1:

```
domain.com/MyLink/
```

Problem is, I need the behaviour from server 1 on my Cloud server. I have a lot of articles in my database, and I cannot change the links easily, so there must be some simple way to setup behavior 1?

How do I fix that?

Comment: You can fix links dynamically on page load. On server side, or javascript.

Comment: But if server 1 has the behavior I need, isn't it just some server settings? Fix links dynamically seems quite performance heavy compared to things just working out of the box as #1 :)

Comment: I think this is your case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415716/relative-links-with-extension-less-urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, as the [URL Anri posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415716/relative-links-with-extension-less-urls), the problem was how the urls was treated. Server #1 thought it wasn't a dictionary, while #2 did.

I added this code to my web.config, and everything was solved:

```
 <rewrite>
      <rules>

        <!--To always remove trailing slash from the URL-->
        <rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)/$"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

As I wanted that behavior anyway for SEO reasons, it didn't have any unfortunate problems.